# How to replicate Android wallpaper theming?

Tags: c, cielab

So I want to recreate Android 12 new wallpaper theming on other platforms, but I am not sure how the palette generation works. One site (XDA) says that colors need to be extracted then converted to Lab color space, but what comes next?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have figured out how the colors are supposed to be generated. First, extracted colors are converted to perceptually uniform color models, such as L*a*b* (or L*u*v*, alternatively). Then, generating a color palette by adjusting the lightness but keeping the hue/chroma (i.e. a monochromatic palette)

Comment: This is the simplest method to replicate that wallpaper-based theming system, but the actual processing method used is more complex (including shifting hue).